# Creating a lists of sums from a list

Tags: list, collections, groovy

Is there a groovier way of doing this? That is, create a new list from the sum of groups of 3 numbers from the original list.

```
    myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    newList = []

    while (myList.size > 0) {
      newList.add(myList.pop() + myList.pop() + myList.pop())
    }

    println newList.reverse()

    [6, 15, 24]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
myList.collate(3).collect {it.sum()}
```

or with just a fine use of spread operator `*`

```
myList.collate(3)*.sum()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can group the list into sublists of 3 elements with [collate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int%29):

```
groovy:000> myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
===> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
groovy:000> myList.collate(3)
===> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Then sum each sublist; the sum can be done with inject:

```
groovy:000> myList.collate(3)*.inject(0) { sum, i -> sum + i }
===> [6, 15, 24]
```

or just use this convenience method [sum](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/06/groovy-goodness-revisited-getting-sum.html)

```
groovy:000> myList.collate(3)*.sum()
===> [6, 15, 24]
```